# Dynamic sorting order in Crystal Report 2008

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I am developing a report with Crystal Report 2008. My work is done except sorting the report dynamically based on a user parameter. The report will be sorted by “CreateDate” column based on the “SortedTo” parameter value. It means if the  parameter “SortedTo” contains “Ascending“ value then the report will be sorted like: “Order By CreateDate asc” . If the parameter “SortedTo” contains “Descending” then the report will be sorted like: “Order By CreateDate Desc”.

Can anyone help me to find a solution? I tried with Sorted expert but sorted order (asc/desc) cannot be made dynamically. So any suggestions or help will be appreciable.

Thanks to you all.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931846/crystal-report-group-sort-order